# turns the music back off

Tags: sentence-construction

> I put on some music. My wife starts singing along. I look at her, **then abruptly turns the music back off.**

My question is about the part in bold. Is it grammatical and correct with the information I have given you?

Would **then abruptly turns the music off again** be more natural?

Comment: As it stands, it's not clear who is turning the music off. If it's you, you need 'turn' rather than 'turns'.

Comment: With 'turn' for 'turns', I think both variants are fine. The slight awkwardness comes from the use of 'abruptly'---in my opinion, one *usually* calls the actions of *others* 'abrupt', because there is a slight connotation of unexpectedness. In this case I might prefer 'promptly' or 'swiftly'.

Comment: _I put on some music. My wife starts singing along. I look at her, then abruptly turn the music off._ You could simply turn it off, no need to use the word 'back'. Also 'again' would suggest you priorly did that once or more already. And it should be 'turn' not 'turns'.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh you are correct that neither 'back' nor 'again' are required, strictly speaking. However, they are both perfectly natural. I do not agree with your logical argument against the use of 'again', because the 'again' refers to the *state* of the music being off rather than the action of turning off.

Comment: @legatrix I am sorry, but I did not understand how are you referring to it as a state. I mean how can the music be off? I certainly did not catch you with that. I will recommend if we talk in the chat room. Because they may go as a long conversation, and I do not wish to crowd it in here.

Comment: Maybe not clear, sorry. The music can be off (one state) or on (another state). If it is off, then on, then off, then it is in its initial state again. Just like water can be cold, then hot, then cold again.

Comment: [Additional comment for the linguistically interested:] (See the large amount of Google hits for "turn it off again".) I suspect that some people might object that the 'off' belongs to the phrasal verb 'turn off' and does not separately denote a state as in "she hammered the metal flat", but I believe this is to confuse syntax with semantics.

Answer (score 1):

With 'turn' for 'turns', I think both variants are fine. (Others prefer *back* or neither; see comments.)

The slight awkwardness comes from the use of 'abruptly'---in my opinion, one usually calls the actions of others 'abrupt', because there is a slight connotation of unexpectedness. In this case I might prefer 'promptly' or 'swiftly'.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of "idiomacy", not "grammar / syntax" as such. But as [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28turn%20it%20back%20off%2A10%29%2C%28turn%20it%20off%20again%2A10%29%2Cturn%20it%20back%20on%2Cturn%20it%20on%20again&year_start=1910&year_end=2010&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28turn%20it%20back%20off%20%2A%2010%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28turn%20it%20off%20again%20%2A%2010%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cturn%20it%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cturn%20it%20on%20again%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C(turn%20it%20back%20off%20*%2010)%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C(turn%20it%20off%20again%20*%2010)%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cturn%20it%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cturn%20it%20on%20again%3B%2Cc0) shows, there's a marked preference for turning something ***back on***, as opposed to turning it ***off again*** (rather than turning it ***back off*** and ***on again***)...

[image]

Note that I only multiplied the hits for the ***off*** versions by 10 so they'd all fit on the same graph. We're only interested in the *relative* preference for the ***back / again*** versions - it's irrelevant that both ***off*** versions are less common than both ***on*** versions.

Syntactically, it's perfectly okay to speak of *turning something **back off*** (so long as it had *previously*<sup>1</sup> been turned off on at least one occasion). We're just much more likely to speak of *turning it **off again***.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that native speakers wouldn't usually include either ***again*** or ***back*** unless the referent had been *explicitly* "turned off" before. In OP's context, that doesn't seem to be the case (presumably, the speaker only turned the music off on a single occasion within the current "frame of reference").

But *sometimes* in such contexts we can use ***back*** or ***again*** to imply "reverting" (to some previous state), as opposed to ***repeating something that was done before***.

Comment: I thought "idiomaticity" was a more commonly understood/recognized word than "idiomacy".

Comment: I haven't looked into that one (*yet*, as I write! :) I suppose they're both more common than, say, "idiomaticness" - but whichever version I write, I'm likely to put it in scare quotes at least the first time I use it.

Comment: ...Yup! It [certainly looks like you're right!](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=idiomaticity%2Cidiomacy%2Cidiomaticness&year_start=1910&year_end=2010&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cidiomaticity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cidiomacy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cidiomaticness%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cidiomaticity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cidiomacy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cidiomaticness%3B%2Cc0) But if I look at [just 1910-1950](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=idiomaticity%2Cidiomacy%2Cidiomaticness&year_start=1910&year_end=1950&corpus=26&smoothing=3) it's a whole nother story!